# How to www-forward to a WordPress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to setup a www-forward that points a domain name to a WordPress category.

Example: www.myexample.com forwarded to www.mywordpress.com/category. 
This returns an "Internal Server Error" though, and my host says that this is due to WordPress not making physical file structures.

Maybe this should be in ServerFault, but I'm asking here if there are some ways to fix this in the WordPress settings, or with a plugin or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly.
Try Create a forward to a php page that then forward to the wordpress category.
eg.

On the server forward to www.myexample.com/to-category.php

Then in the to-category.php

```
<?php header("location:http://www.mywordpress.com/category"); ?>
```

That will send the viewer to your category page.

Comment: Thanks janlindso.Sorry I see I missed that. You will need the http:// or https://